# how can I remove a duplicates from sorted array?

Tags: arrays, c

what I'm supposed to do is to sort a list of prices and choose one of the values as ordered but there are duplicated prices in the array how can I remove them?

I have like 9 arrays and I need to sort them and print out the value of the order (lowest price, second lowest price, etc..) sorry for not clearing that out.

```
int lowestPrice(int array[], int size, int order){

int tempArray[size];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tempArray[i] = array[i];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (size_t j = i; j < size; j++)
            if (tempArray[j] < tempArray[i]) {
                int tmp = tempArray[i];
                tempArray[i] = tempArray[j];
                tempArray[j] = tmp;
            }
    int j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size -1; i++){
        if(tempArray[i] != tempArray[i+1])
        {
            tempArray[j] = tempArray[i];
            j++;
        } tempArray[j] = tempArray[i-1];
    }

    return tempArray[order];    
}
```

Comment: If the lowest prices are duplicate prices, that is just the lowest price. Why care about removing duplicates?

Comment: @kan3 It is unclear why you are doing all this when what you need is to return one value.

Comment: You mean you have a possibly-unordered array of x number of prices, some of which may be duplicates, and you need to put each unique price in order, then return the nth one specified by `order`?

Comment: the user will order one of the prices like in this example  { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };

Comment: So you need to sort that array from small to big, get rid of the duplicates, then return the price at the `order` position?

Comment: yes that's how it should work

Comment: You can also *not* remove the duplicates from the array, but make your print loop ignore a row if the price was the same as last.

Comment: I think that's what I'm trying to do in the code above but I don't understand it clearly

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your last "for" with:

```
int j = 0;
for (size_t i = 1; i < size ; i++){
    if(tempArray[i] != tempArray[i-1])
    {
        tempArray[j] = tempArray[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```

What you want to do is to keep the first one of each number, so if the current one is equal to the last one, it will ignore it.